# Looking for macros to typeset syntax in more conventional way

Tags: best-practices, syntax

I want to create a note about PSTricks and I need macros to typeset syntax in more conventional way that is adopted by most computer scientists. For example, I need a pair of `>` and `<` but they must be slimmer than the usual ones. Here I used `\guillemotright` and `\guillemotleft` as I could not find the better ones.

Here is my MWE, could you help me to accomplish my objective? Best practice is also welcome!

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\def\guillemetright{\guillemotright}% from now on we must hide the wrong terms.
\def\guillemetleft{\guillemotleft}% from now on we must hide the wrong terms.

\def\gr{\guillemetright}%I need a single > but not as big as the usual >.
\def\gl{\guillemetleft}%I need a single < but not as big as the usual <.

\newcommand\com[1]{\textbf{\textbackslash #1}}
\newcommand\opt[1][\textit{kv-options}]{\textcolor{blue}{[\gl\ensuremath{#1}\gr]}}
\newcommand\man[1]{\textcolor{red}{\{\gl\ensuremath{#1}\gr\}}}


\begin{document}

\section{Projection}
\fbox{\com{pstProjection}\opt\man{A}\man{B}\man{P_1,\ldots,P_n}\opt[P_1',\ldots,P_n']}

\noindent will project orthogonally the point $P_i$ on the line $\overline{AB}$. 
\end{document}
```

Note: `\man` (mandatory) in red, `\opt` (optional) in blue, `\com` (command) in black.

Comment: If you are doing this often, then you might want to look at something like the `listings` package to automate the highlighting of different portions.

Comment: @PeterGrill: If you have time, please give me an example. I haven't elaborated the `listing` thoroughly. I will compare and might use your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `\langle` and `\rangle`:

```
\newcommand\meta[1]{$\langle#1\rangle$}
\newcommand\opt[1][\textit{kv-options}]{\textcolor{blue}{[\meta{#1}]}}
\newcommand\man[1]{\textcolor{red}{\{\meta{#1}\}}}
```

With it you get, from

```
\com{pstProjection}\opt\man{A}\man{B}\man{P_1,\ldots,P_n}\opt[P_1',\ldots,P_n']
```

the following result

[image]

The alternative version using

```
\newcommand{\meta}[1]{\guilsinglleft$#1$\guilsinglright}
```

doesn't seem as good

[image]

Comment: Is there a single guillemot [explained here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillemets) in LaTeX ?

Comment: Yes, there is. But the result is not good, IMO. I'll add it for comparison.

Comment: The main brackets look clearer when using single guillemots I think. Thank  you.

Comment: @DamienWalters: you can always make them `\bigl[ ... \bigr]`, this should help.

Comment: @DamienWalters -- *please* don't call them "guillemots".  (yes, i know, adobe got it wrong; acknowledged, according to wikipedia, in the 3rd edition of the postscript language reference manual, p.783, character set endnote 3.)  guillemots are small black sea birds.  the correct term is "guillemets".

Comment: @barbarabeeton: OK. I will define `\def\guillemetright{\guillemotright}` and `\def\guillemetleft{\guillemotleft}` from now on. :-)