# Error presenting an image

Tags: beamer, graphics, errors

I want the third page of my document to include an image (JPEG) but I can't figure out what's wrong with my code. Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\title[Artificial Neural Network]{Introduction  to ANN\\Artificial Neural Network}
\author{Gigili}
\date{January 6, 2013}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage{}

\end{frame}





 \begin{frame}{continue}

\includegraphics{<Sample>}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Here's the folder where I saved the image and the sample code:

[image]

The error I am getting is:

> LaTeX Error: File '< Sample >' not  found.

Comment: Try to remove `<>` in `\includegraphics{<Sample>}` and then compile it. I tried it with an image of mine and it worked.

Comment: You should always state the exact error message you get so others can help you better. Also examples should be minimal, e.g. the first `frame` here is not required etc.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: You're right. I was talking about it in chat and forgot other people here don't know what I am talking about! I'll edit my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- first, it's not recommended to choose the same name for your .tex file and your image.
- As mentioned in the comments, I removed '<>' and it worked:

  ```
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{neuron}
  ```

Note that the image was renamed to *neuron*.

Comment: The `<..>` are often used, including on this site, to mark a variable text, e.g., `<name>` means to add a name here and `<filename>` means to add a file name here. The `< >` act here as delimiters to see where the template starts and ends and should be replaced when filling in the real content.

Comment: [Meta Syntax](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48123/19356).

Comment: This answer does _not_ show how to include a `jpeg` picture because it doesn't refer to the extension of the filename. Of course it's possible to rely on the capability of the `graphicx` package to define a default file extension, define conversions, and search paths, but this is not a MWE that shows how to use them.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: I didn't claim that it is.

Comment: Well, your _question_ is about presenting a _JPEG_ picture and you provide an _answer_ to your question, which suggests the answer demonstrates how to include a JPEG picture.